# jQuery UI Autocomplete - returning selection further down on page. Not sure how to remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="pagination-centered text-center">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." id="searchBox">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="pagination-centered text-center">
        <p id="result"></p>
    </div>
```

```
var uniq = availableTags.reduce(function(a,b){
    if (a.indexOf(b) < 0 ) a.push(b);
        return a;
},[]);

$(function() {  
    $("#searchBox").autocomplete({
        source: uniq
    });
});
```

This is my HTML and JS associated with the jQuery UI Autocomplete. The Autocomplete itself works fine. It pulls all the data correctly, fills it in the search box, etc. However, it also displays the chosen value further down the page outside of the search box in an area I don't have designated for anything in my HTML. I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

Comment: Need to see if there are any styling or CSS that might effect positioning. Do you have a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Yeah just made one. Here it is: [https://jsfiddle.net/ac52cb5x/](https://jsfiddle.net/ac52cb5x/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an accessibility feature intended for disabled people but looks like it has some bug .This div with (*ui-helper-hidden-accessible*) class gets updated every time you hover your cursor or when typing in the textbox .Since it is meant for visually impaired users to be consumed only through some assistive technology(like readers or something) hiding it through CSS would be the best option

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { display:none; }
```